# How to make an exception based on the character found

Tags: java

I made a program that's supposed to read and store strings, and do some more stuff later on with them, here's an example string:

```
AAAAAAAAABBBBBBCCCC
BBBBBBBAAAAACCCCCCC
```

I want to make an exception in the scanner method, so that when I read it  and it finds un-wanted characters like '_' and '!' or 'f' it returns an exception and stops the rest of the program.

Basically I want it to JUST allow 3 characters (A, B and C). I have  no idea atm on how to write this, but there's probably a java method on how to do this :D

So how do I write an exception that only allows these 3?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, CharException {

  Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:/path/hehe.txt"));
  if (characters found are different than 'a', 'b', 'c') {
       break;

   }
```

I know that looks horrible, but yeah that's basically what I'm looking into writting. Thanks.

Comment: why not search on how to check if file contains anything else?

Comment: Key words: Java String Regex Match

Comment: if you really need to check every line, why not use a regex (have a look at `String.matches()`) or check each character individually?

Comment: What did you intend to do with the `Scanner` if the content is valid? So far you haven't read any data, so you can't validate it.

Comment: @slim OP very likely intended to use the `Scanner` to read from the file, likely using `nextLine()`. Sure, `BufferedReader` would be better, but why ask what OP was gonna do with `Scanner` if content is valid? How would you know content is valid unless you already used the scanner to read the file content? If content is valid, OP wouldn't intend to use `Scanner` any more, since it's positioned at end of file by then.

Comment: @Andreas I ask because then we can tell OP how to reject what they've read. We don't know until we know which read method they intend to use. (On a side note, I wonder why all the Java newbie questions use `Scanner`? I've never used it in real code in 20 years.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex

```
String s = "AAAAAAAAABBBBBBCCCC";
if(s.replaceAll("[ABC]", "").length()>0){
    //incorrect
}else{
    //correct
}
```

It removes all `A`, `B` and `C`, and then checks if the length is greater than 0.

Or

```
if(s.matches("[ABC]+")){
    //correct
}else{
    //incorrect
}
```

Note that it is case sensitive. Also, if the length of the String is 0, it would give *incorrect*

Comment: `replaceAll()` is probably quite inefficient, better use `matches("[ABC]+")`.

Comment: Hmm, if you have a look at the implementation of `Matcher.replaceAll()` (which is where `String.replaceAll()` leads to) you see that there's quite a lot of code involved in replacing so although it's probably negligible for short strings it can become quite significant for larger strings or a large number of them.

Comment: *"No need of using Scanner"* Well, OP will need *something* to read from the file. Regex can't read files, so that statement is wrong.

Comment: @Andreas Read up the second paragraph of the question. I guess you already know what I meant :) But it's ambiguous, so I'll edit it anyway.

Comment: thank you for your new information i appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to find if the file contains only your specified characters, it would be like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:/path/hehe.txt"));
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[ABC]+");
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
  if (!p.matcher(s.nextLine()).find()) {
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your file in a `Readable` that rejects invalid characters:

```
 public class ValidatingReadable implements Readable {

      private Reader wrappedReadable;

      public ValidatingReadable(Readable wrappedReadable) {
          this.wrappedReadable = wrappedReadable;
      }

      public int read(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException {
          int r = wrappedReadable.read(cb);
          for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {
               char c = cb.get(i);
               if( c < 'A' || c > 'C' ) {
                   throw new IOException("Invalid input:" + c);
               }
          }
          return r;
      }
```

You can use this anywhere a `Readable` is accepted, for example:

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
    new ValidatingReader(
        new FileReader("C:/path/hehe.txt")));
```

This is an example of the *Decorator Pattern*.